# Django - Form Signed up. Get Name from URL and save in hidden first_name

Tags: django

On my form signed up I want to override the behavior

I want to get from url `www.example.com/accounts/signup/?name=Michael`

and save the name as first_name.
But I need that input first_name hidden

What i've tried:
class SignupForm(forms.Form):

```
def signup(self, request, user):
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.save()


<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ form.first_name }}" value="test" />

  {% endif %}
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>
```

So The form would be something like: e-mail; password but also save first_name as Michael.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You mean you wish to use first_name as a placeholder? What is the problem you are facing with your approach? It did not work?

Comment: Url will pass the control to the signup view from where you can insert first_name in the form instance and then pass the instance to the template. Render the first_name as placeholder in the form. This is what you need?

Comment: To signup i just have e-mail and password. But I want to get name from url, and save it as first_name. The problem is, Im using Django-Allauth and I dont know how to override it. @gautamaggarwal